# is it possible to get running application UI information

Tags: bash, tty

This is a difficult question to even ask. Lets say I spawn a nano or vi instance in a shell/screen/tmux is there anyway to retrieve the applications UI in a raw format?

So for example if I am running nano which looks like the following:
[image: visual aid for nano]

is there anyway to get this UI as it is seen but in raw bytecode (for example) so I can rebuild the view on another application that is interacting with the procress (think confusing remote reverse shell)

Comment: Edit question to tell us what your goal it (not how you think you will solve it).

Comment: Have you looked at vnc?